# Pivoting dates in a month out as columns; possible without dynamic sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

So I have a SQL table that contains time-clock information like this.  The number of minutes an employee was at work on a given date.  The table holds several years worth of but is missing Saturdays and Sundays and other non work days/holidays (with occasional exceptions).

```
 EmployeeID   Date Attended   Total Minutes
 -----------------------------------
 001          '11/01/2011'    319
 002          '11/01/2011'    355
 003          '11/01/2011'    352
 001          '11/02/2011'    340
 002          '11/02/2011'    322
 003          '11/02/2011'    351
```

I need to write a pivot that will show the data like this in a report that summarizes attendance to a given month.

```
 EmployeeId  '11/01/2011'  '11/02/2011' ....  (for all dates in a month)
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 001         319           340
 002         355           322
 003         352           351
```

I have a solution that works (see below)... **but my approach uses dynamic sql** to build the pivot statement from the days in a given month. In the back of my mind I keep thinking there has to be a way that does not use dynamic SQL - but it's not coming to me.  Any suggestions... **am I stuck with Dynamic SQL?**

```
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @headers VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @lowdate Date 
DECLARE @highdate Date

SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',[' + cast(Attended as varchar) + ']',
                     '[' + cast(Attended as varchar)+ ']')
FROM TimeAttended WHERE attended >= @date and attended <= @highdate
GROUP BY Attended

SELECT @headers = COALESCE(@Headers + ',Sum([' + cast(Attended as varchar) + ']) as [' + cast(Attended as varchar) + ']',
                     'Sum([' + cast(Attended as varchar)+ ']) as [' + cast(Attended as varchar) + ']')
FROM TimeAttended WHERE attended >= @date and attended <= @highdate
GROUP BY Attended

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(8000)
SET @query = '
SELECT employeeid, ' + @headers + '
FROM TimeAttended 
PIVOT
 (
 Sum(TotalMinutes)
 FOR [Attended]
 IN (' + @columns + ')
 )
 AS p group by employeeid'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the obvious one of using dynamic SQL (which I generally prefer to avoid if possible), there are two static options.

The first is to get the rows as normal, and then pivoting the results in your display code (which you're somewhat doing regardless).  This is assuming you're generating a report of some sort, and have the requisite processing power avaliable.

The second requires thinking about the data slightly differently.
Instead of creating the statement to look at a *specific* set of dates, code it to look at the *set* of the last 31 days (from some given date).
That is, column2 is the given date, column3 is the given date - 1 day, etc:

```
SELECT a.Id, COALESCE(b.Minutes, 0), COALESCE(c.Minutes, 0), (etc)
FROM Employees as a
LEFT JOIN TimeClock as b
ON b.EmployeeId = a.id
AND b.Date = @Given
LEFT JOIN TimeClock as c
ON C.EmployeeId = a.Id
AND c.Date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Given)
(etc)
```

... And then mapping it to column1 of the results to column1 of the display table, etc.

Comment: This is an intriguing option... I'm going to throw some brain power at it and get back to you.

Comment: This works... I'm going to do some tests to see how it performs as compared to the way I'm already doing it before I accept but +1 for giving me a creative approach that doesn't use dynamic sql.

Comment: The multiple joins approach wins.  I realized after starting to work on the reporting services report that the dynamic way made it impossible to map columns in the report.  By naming them 1 - 31 instead I can use the functions within my rdlc to name the columns that actual date based on it's own date add.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, it's better to think of (and translate to screen) the data this way.  The only time I've had to use Dynamic SQL was when I was dealing with a denormalized table, where I had to select the relevant columns (6 _rolling_ months out of a year, where each month was a column... and I had to ocasionally select from 2 rows, not one).  If your tables are set up correctly, you almost never need to use dynamic statements (even some dynamic search options can be controlled statically).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from dynamic SQL,
If each bit of output is going to belong to just one month, then you could hardcode all days from 1 to 31:

```
with data as (
  select *
  from (
    values
     (001,          '20111101',    319),
     (002,          '20111101',    355),
     (003,          '20111101',    352),
     (001,          '20111102',    340),
     (002,          '20111102',    322),
     (003,          '20111102',    351)
  ) foo (EmployeeID, [Date], [Minutes])
),
prepared_data as (
  select EmployeeID, [Minutes], day([date]) as [day]
  from data
)
select *
from
  prepared_data
  pivot (min([Minutes]) for [day] in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31])) pvt
;
```

And then at a later stage hide or ignore in some other way columns that only have `null`s.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know the values ahead of time you have to use Dynamic SQL if you want the column headers to be based on values.

The only database that can do this is MS Access' TRANSFORM

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I just don't like dynamic sql when I can at all avoid it.