# Building SSRS time series report from SQL datetime column

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I need to create a SSRS report where the user specifies the start and end date (e.g. March 2012 to July 2012) and the result is a report with the following headings:

```
   User  Department  Product  Mar-12  Apr-12  May-12  Jun-12  Jul-12
```

The dates are stored in a datetime column (e.g.2012-06-11 14:48:04.787) in my SQL table which I'm using to build the time-series report.

Do I need to convert/transpose my SQL table first? Or should I be processing this in SSRS?

Your advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question it appears all your dates are in a single datetime column and your trying to display them, formatted as a month, in a single report with the report columns grouped and renamed based on the month.  This is a pivot and I don't think you can do that within SSRS.  The dataset will already need to be pivoted by the time SSRS gets it.

So, to me this sounds like something you'll have to do both pre and post SSRS.  I did a similar report using days of the month.  [You can see the winning answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8513270/261997) as opposed to months of the year.

Thinking through your logice, I think you'll probably have to build the query with the pivot and then send to SSRS.  On the SSRS side you need 12 columns for all 12 months and then put some logic to hide the ones that don't get data.  Your original pivot will need to be smart enough to pass the empty months so SSRS doesn't error out.  The end result will appear the same but needs a lot of pre-thought and design effort up front.

Comment: thanks so much for your advice and ideas RThomas! The logic makes sense - i will give it a go! Was hoping there'd be an easier solution to this though haha!

Comment: good luck, just keep in mind how proud you'll be when it's all up and working

Answer (score 0):

You do the processing using SSRS - you would design it in the GUI editor(BIDS ) , and you can customize things using the VBasic code also(i.e, dates and logic)

Looks like you need an intro, I really recommend this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vB9iDurRtRM)